# I tried to explain why I had been delayed but he ..... my excuse as pathetic

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

Which option fits best the following sentence.

> I tried to explain why I had been delayed but he ..... my excuse as
>   pathetic.
>
> 1.ignored
>
> 2.disregarded
>
> 3.dismissed
>
> 4.refused

For me all the options suit to the sentence in meaning. I saw 'to dismiss an excuse' and  'refuse an excuse' on search results. Is 'dismiss an excuse'  the most common one?

Answer (score 3):

"Dismiss" is the best choice here.

"dismiss" meant that he listened to you but he didn't accept what you said.

"ignore" meant that he didn't listen at all.

"refused" means that he rejected a request to do something.

"disregarded" means that he didn't care.

Since in the sentence he called your excuse pathetic, it implies he listened to what you said and thought about it, and then replied with considering your excuse as pathetic.

Each word can have nuances behind its use, that's a tough thing about learning other languages - trying to get the hang of how to use which words.